# How to truncate file used to redirect stdout

Tags: linux, bash, redirection, stdout

I am trying to truncate a file, used for redirected stdout. For example:

```
ping localhost>/tmp/test.log
```

If I call `rm /tmp/test.log` then redirection stops but the command works.

If I call `truncate -s0 /tmp/test.log` or `>/tmp/test.log` or `echo ..` and etc. redirection works but the file contains leading zeros because stream position has not changed.

How can I truncate the file?

Comment: Note the `rm /tmp/test.log` removes the file entry from the directory but the file itself still exists, takes space and grows in inode-based filesystem. It will be truly deleted when it's not in use anymore, i.e. when your `ping` is terminated or even later.

Comment: Just make the truncation part of your procedure. Send 10.000 pings or whatever, delete the file and write a new one.

Comment: What do you mean; what do you want to happen? Do you want to repeatedly `ping` your `localhost`, and keep updating `/tmp/test.log`, so that it contains only the output stats from the most recent ICMP response?

Answer (score 3):

You need to understand Unix file systems before you can answer this question.

The only thing `rm` does is erase the files *name*, effectively a pointer from your directory structure to the disk blocks.

When you run

```
ping localhost > /tmp/test.log
rm /tmp/test.log
```

redirection does not stop.  The command keeps running, and data keeps accumulating in your disk area.  You simply have no way to access this data because you erased its name.

You are free to create a completely unrelated file named `/tmp/test.log`.

As you noted, by attempting to truncate the file, you get rid of the data that used to be there, but the internal file descriptor knows the position in the file it points to and writes after the end of the file extend the file. Hence the leading zeros.

If you want to "reset" the redirection, then you need to kill the `ping` program, erase or truncate the `/tmp/test.log` file, and then restart the `ping` program.

You could also use a program like `rotatelogs`

```
ping localhost | rotatelogs ping.out.%Y%m%d.%H%M 600
```

to rotate the log file either based on the elapsed time or the size of the file.

Comment: "You simply have no say to access this data because you erased the file system pointer." In general this is not true. The trick is to use `/proc/<PID>/fd/0` path.

Answer (score 2):

Plan ahead:

1. Truncate or delete the file, if it exists.
2. Use `>>` instead of `>`.

This way you will take advantage of the fact that `>>` is essentially "always seek to end of file" while `>` maintains a pointer to the last written location.

Then you can truncate the file and `>>` will obey. See [this answer of mine](https://superuser.com/a/1342490/432690), it investigates the exact behavior you need.